# Database does not send any data to application when ran for a larger data set

Tags: mariadb

I have a query that runs fine when returning a smaller dataset (~1 million rows), but when I increase the number of rows it returns (~15-20 million) it will send nothing to the application.

My query has two inner joins, both that use an index. There is also an index on the date range that is used for smaller data sets, but not for larger data sets. I have tried forcing this key to no avail.

In show processlist the query seems to be stuck on "Writing to net".

I am using Mariadb 10.

My application requires that I get my data as soon as possible with as little reduction to throughput as possible, but some is acceptable.

The query runs fine using the mysql cli.

Explain for small dataset:

```
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| id   | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                     | key              | key_len | ref                                | rows     | filtered | Extra                 |
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | event_list   | range  | event_type_index,time_event_index | time_event_index | 12      | NULL                               | 10091044 |   100.00 | Using index condition |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | misc_details | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY          | 4       | usage.event_list.event_id   |        1 |   100.00 |                       |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | profiles     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY          | 4       | usage.event_list.profile_id |        1 |   100.00 | Using where           |
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+------------------+---------+------------------------------------+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Explain for large dataset:

```
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                     | key     | key_len | ref                                | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | event_list   | ALL    | event_type_index,time_event_index | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                               | 65610043 |    38.03 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | misc_details | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY | 4       | usage.event_list.event_id   |        1 |   100.00 |             |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | profiles     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY | 4       | usage.event_list.profile_id |        1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Using FORCE INDEX lets it run for a large dataset with the same explain, but does not work.

```
CREATE TABLE (key information for relative fields):

  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`),
  KEY `event_type_index` (`event_type`),
  KEY `profile_index` (`profile_id`),
  KEY `time_event_index` (`timeOf`,`event_type`)


SELECT [various fields]
FROM event_list
INNER JOIN misc_details USING (event_id)
INNER JOIN profiles USING (profile_id)
WHERE event_type IN ([various ids]) and timeOf BETWEEN [date range]
```

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to get the execution plans for both variants and compare them. If it does not help you then add those to your question together with the `create table` statements for the used tables.

Comment: Ah, please add the queries too.

Comment: the index on `(timeOf, event_type)` might be better the other way around, because when range is used on `timeOf`, no more direct filtering is possible for `event_type`, whereas `(event_type, timeOf)` with `IN ([ids])` can do multiple direct accesses, one for each event_type, and get the time ranges efficiently. That will help a lot if `[various ids]` is not too big (meaning not matching too many rows).

Comment: I don't think changing an index is really an option in this case due to the size of the table and other applications using it.

Comment: You can just add new one, keeping this one intact (yes is may be important for other queries). MariaDB can do some *inplace* alters and adding index is one of them - `alter online table <name> add index i(c1,c2);` or `alter table ... algorithm=inplace;` (those two should be equivalent in MariaDB, they are not in MySQL, where the latter is the right one). Only problem would be Galera Cluster which will lock-up even on *online* alters unless you switch into *rolling schema updates* but you do not mention that. Master-slave replication should take it without problems.